# Google banned my site, how can I clear virus from my site?

Tags: malware

When you enter URL of the websites in a web-browser, warning is shown. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to find the malicious code on your website that's causing the warning and remove it. I'd suggest looking at the page's source code for anything that looks out of the ordinary, or that you know you didn't put there. Most likely will be some JavaScript code.